# How to hide checkbox 'Notify user of new account' for roles who can add user

Tags: 8, hooks

Have scenario in `Drupal 8`, where Editor role can add users with dummy mail and sends login info through phone SMS to added users.

Hence, the checkbox `'Notify user of new account'` should be hidden from the Add User form - so that emails do not bounce from dummy mail ids

Yes, checkbox does not do so when unchecked. But, I want this to be unclickable for Editors or set to unclicked OR hidden for good!

Comment: Did you try a simple approach using hook_form_alter?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a very simple module to do that

Module and folder name **suppress_notify** but can be anything you choose

2 files inside

**suppress_notify.info.yml**

```
name: 'suppress_notify'
type: module
description: 'Suppress notify for non admin users'
core: 8.x
package: 'Custom'
```

**suppress_notify.module**

```
<?php

use Drupal\user\Entity\User;

/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function suppress_notify_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  //for registration form
  if($form_id == "user_register_form"){
    //for non admin users
    if(!User::load(\Drupal::currentUser()->id())->hasRole('administrator')){
      //disable the notify field
      $form["account"]["notify"]["#access"] = false;
    }  
  }
}
```

Enable the module and all non `administrator` users should have the `Notify user of new account` hidden

Comment: Accept my thanks dear. That was spot on ans did the work for me